# If I connect my new Wi-Fi 6E router with the ethernet cable to that router I have to buy, will I have all the benefits of the Wi-Fi 6E or not?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, wifi-configuration

I have to upgrade my internet provider router, but the upgrade model support Wi-Fi 6, not the 6E.

If I connect my new Wi-Fi 6E router (another one I've bought recently) with the ethernet cable to that router I have to buy, will I have all the benefits of the Wi-Fi 6E or not?

Basically the question is about "lossless/upgradable Wi-Fi standard support":

1. Wi-Fi 6 (main router) --> Wi-Fi 6E (other router)
2. Wi-Fi 6E (main router) --> Wi-Fi 6E (other router)

Which one? 1 or 2?

Comment: Can you disable wireless on the ISPs modem/router? I run a personal WiFi router following the ISPs modem and there's no problems, I just have to remind my ISP (they're annoying this way) to turn off their WiFi every once in a while. "lossless/upgradeable Wi-Fi standard support" is meaningless: There's no such thing. You currently have two different wireless routers, and they WILL conflict with each other in the air, so you want to make sure one is turned off. You want to use the 6E one, the one you own, and so tell the ISP to turn theirs off.

Comment: @music2myear Nope, the main router have the telephone line port and all the configuration stuff provided by them to make the telephone line and the internet connection working properly, then the other router will be my personal gaming router

Comment: For clarity, call that your "modem", because that is its primary component and role. Call your ISP to see is they'll disable wireless on it.

Comment: The wifi just replaces the cable between an end device and the AP/Router it is connected to. assuming you have set things up for a wifi-mesh or separate SSIDs on different bands/channels, (or the devices are a long way apart), then the wifi of an AP/Router that you are NOT connected to cannot have any impact on the connection to one you are connected to. its like asking whether a switch you are not connected to can impact your connection to the one you are wired to.

Comment: Do note, Having a WiFi broadcaster that supports a certain spec will not automatically mean that you can use its full spec. Your client devices must also support that same spec. If your wireless devices don't support WiFi 6e, but they do support WiFi 6, changing the router has absolutely no impact whatsoever, as the 6e router will fall back to 6 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

### Whatever WiFi is on that ISP provided router/modem is utterly irrelevant if you choose to use your own router.

You ask this:

> “If I connect my new Wi-Fi 6E router (another one I've bought recently) with the ethernet cable to that router I have to buy, will I have all the benefits of the Wi-Fi 6E or not?”

The WiFi that is on that ISP provided router/modem is utterly irrelevant of you plan on connecting your own router via ethernet.

All you should do when using the ISP provided router/modem is turn off the WiFi and set it to bridge mode. You will have all the benefits of WiFi 6E if you use it. Again, the ISP router is irrelevant as far as WiFi goes if you don’t connect to it.

You also say this:

> Basically the question is about "lossless/upgradable Wi-Fi standard support":
>
> 1. Wi-Fi 6 (main router) --> Wi-Fi 6E (other router)
> 2. Wi-Fi 6E (main router) --> Wi-Fi 6E (other router)
>
> Which one? 1 or 2?

This is makes utterly no sense at all. There is no such thing as “lossless/upgradable Wi-Fi standard support” and your list if 1. or 2. points makes even less sense.

The only thing you need to do is make sure all of your devices connect to your new WiFi 6E router and you should be fine. Mind you, your devices still need to support WiFi 6E to take full advantage of WiFi 6E; otherwise they will connect at whatever connection that they can properly negotiate. Such as WiFi 5 and such.

But please do not overthink this: Just turn off the WiFi on the ISP router and set the ISP router to bridge mode and all should be fine.